# How do I show one prediction using Random Forest?

Tags: python, machine-learning, dataset, random-forest

My sample dataset looks like this -
[image]

My `X_train` features are `'Gender', 'Age', 'Leisure', 'Married', 'Division'`
& y_train is `'Online Shopping'`

My last part of code looks like this -

```
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
#rfc_100 = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=100, random_state=0)

rfc = RandomForestClassifier(random_state=0)

# fit the model

rfc.fit(X_train, y_train)

# Predict the Test set results

y_pred = rfc.predict(X_test)

# Check accuracy score 

from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score

print('Model accuracy score with 10 decision-trees : {0:0.4f}'. format(accuracy_score(y_test, y_pred)))
```

Now my question is How do I use this already built model and check the prediction? For example, I want to give input like this `'Son 19-30 Games Yes C'` & I want to see what is the prediction for Online Shopping interest.Output should be Yes or No.

Encoding process-

```
#Labeling
import category_encoders as ce
encoder1 = ce.OrdinalEncoder(cols=['Gender', 'Age', 'Leisure', 'Married', 'Division'])


X_train = encoder1.fit_transform(X)

X_test = encoder1.transform(X)

encoder2= ce.OrdinalEncoder(cols=['Online Shopping'])

#y_test is True Online Shopping labels
#y_pred is predicted Online Shopping label in test set

y_train = encoder2.fit_transform(y)

y_test = encoder2.transform(y)
```

Output of labeling-
[image]

Comment: Have you tried using `rfc.predict` ?

Comment: No. Does it return output for customized input?

Comment: Also, I need to convert 'Son 19-30 Games Yes C' to label first here

Comment: Yes, it does return output for customized input. You have to structure 'Son 19-30 Games Yes C' in the same way you structure `X_test`, except only for one data point

Comment: I have used category encoder to structure x_test. So if I use category encoder here again for new data frame then the labeling wont be same as before.

Comment: Could you share your code on how you encode your data?

Comment: Yes, I have edited my question

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```py
d = {'Gender': ['Son'], 'Age': ['19-30'], 'Leisure': ['Games'], 'Married': ['Yes'], 'Division': ['C']}
df_dp = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
x_dp = encoder1.transform(df_dp)
print(encoder2.inverse_transform(rfc.predict(x_dp)))
```

where df_dp is the pandas dataframe for the single datapoint, and we encode it then show the prediction using rfc.predict()

I also noticed from your code that `X_train` and `X_test` are from the same dataset. This shouldn't be the case: Training data is used to train the model, while testing data is used to see how good the model is at generalizing to unseen data. This is why your training data and testing data should be different.

Comment: Actually I splitted the dataset before like this

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size = 0.33, random_state = 42)

Comment: You seem to be overriding them with these lines of code 
X_train = encoder1.fit_transform(X)
X_test = encoder1.transform(X)

Comment: I have changed my code to this now encoder1 = ce.OrdinalEncoder(cols=['Gender', 'Age', 'Leisure', 'Married', 'Division'])


X_train = encoder1.fit_transform(X_train)

X_test = encoder1.transform(X_test)

encoder2= ce.OrdinalEncoder(cols=['Online Shopping'])

#y_test is True Online Shopping labels
#y_pred is predicted Online Shopping label in test set

y_train = encoder2.fit_transform(y_train)

y_test = encoder2.transform(y_test)

Comment: That resolves the train test split! Did I manage to answer your question?